# Splitting a C string by full stop character and making an empty string when there is nothing between two of them

Tags: c, string, split, strtok

I'm trying to make a program to convert a string with multiple sentences to a string array for an assignment. The condition is that sentences are split by full stops ('.') and that when there are two full stops directly next to each other, you put an empty string in the array. Currently this is my code, and it doesn't seem to be storing anything in the array for the string "....". Currently, this is my code:

```
pch = strtok(toCamel, ".");
while(pch)
{
    result = realloc(result, sizeof(char*) * ++count);
    if(result == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    result[count - 1] = pch;
    pch = strtok(NULL, ".");
}
```

How can I make it give me empty strings? Also, if a sentence doesn't end with a full stop it is meant to be NULL, e.g. `"The quick brown fox. Jumps over the lazy dog"` would return `{"theQuickBrownFox", NULL}`. Any tips on how I should check for that ending full stop?

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Comment: In order to detect empty strings, don't use `strtok`.  In order to determine if there is a trailing `.`, don't use `strtok`.

Comment: Ok, so what should I use? Being condescending isn't helping anyone...

Comment: There is a function `strsep()` in some libraries (non-standard) which treats every occurrence of the `.` separately whereas `strtok()` does not distinguish multiple consecutive occurrences of the delimiters.

Comment: To give more detail to Scott's objection, `strtok` skips all of the characters in the delimiter string, so "..." gets entirely skipped over.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help guys!